# No puedo compilar drivers

Tags: linux, debian, compilar, makefile

Desde hace un tiempo que tengo Linux(Parrot OS basado en Debian), y cada vez que quiero compilar(sobre todo drivers) me reporta este error el terminal:

> /usr/src/linux-headers-4.16.0-parrot5-common/scripts/Makefile.build:329:
>   fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo
>   '/root/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o'
>   make[4]: ***
>   [/root/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o]
>   Error 1 /usr/src/linux-headers-4.16.0-parrot5-common/Makefile:1575:
>   fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo
>   '*module*/root/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux'
>   make[3]:** 
>   [_module_/root/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux] Error
>   2 Makefile:146: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'sub-make'
>   make[2]:  **[sub-make] Error 2 Makefile:8: fallo en las instrucciones
>   para el objetivo 'all' make[1]: *** [all] Error 2 make[1]: se sale del
>   directorio '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.16.0-parrot5-amd64' Makefile:403:
>   fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'LINUX' make: *** [LINUX]
>   Error 2

He instalado y reinstalado mil veces los headers con apt-get install gcc, y solo me dice que ya estan instalados.
Pero el error parece ser de headers.

Cómo podría solucionarlo?
Gracias
Un saludo

Comment: Hola, ya esta el update hecho, y con el build-essential, me dice como gcc, que ya esta actualizado

Comment: He reintentado compilar tras el update, y sigue dando el error

Comment: Tambien intente el de build-essential, he hecho el de make y me dice que tambien esta instalado ya

Comment: orden de los comandos : ´make´, ´make test ´, ´sudo make install ´

Comment: lo unico que se me ocurre es que bajastes un paquete que no es el correcto

Comment: Si hago make:
`make -C tools
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/unknown/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
/usr/bin/ld: no se puede abrir el fichero de salida bin2h: Permiso denegado
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:2: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'all'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/unknown/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools'
Makefile:339: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'build_tools'
make: *** [build_tools] Error 2
`

Comment: Si hago sudo make para tener permiso root:
`make[4]: *** [/home/../../os/linux/rt_profile.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.16.0-parrot5-common/Makefile:1575: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/unknown/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux] Error 2
Makefile:146: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'sub-make'
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'all'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:403: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'LINUX'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2`

Comment: si hago sudo make test:
`make -C tools test
make[1]: se entra en el directorio '/home/unknown/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools'
make[1]: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo 'test'.  Alto.
make[1]: se sale del directorio '/home/unknown/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/tools'
Makefile:343: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'test'
make: *** [test] Error 2`